# C#: FlatBuffers results are too big

Tags: c#, flatbuffers

According to FlatBuffers [documentation](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/md__schemas.html), Default values don't take space on the wire. I wanted to test this so here's my code:

I'm using this schema:

```
table FlatCard
{
    cardIndex:ushort;
    level:byte = 1;
    damage:ushort;
    health:ushort;
}

root_type FlatCard;
```

And here's the C# code:

```cs
var builder = new FlatBufferBuilder(1);
FlatCard.StartFlatCard(builder);
FlatCard.AddDamage(builder, 10);
Offset<FlatCard> offset = FlatCard.EndFlatCard(builder);
FlatCard.FinishFlatCardBuffer(builder, offset);
byte[] bytes = builder.SizedByteArray();
Console.WriteLine(bytes.Length);
```

The actual result is `24`, but I expect it to be `7` at most (3 ushort and 1 byte). Which part I'm doing/understanding wrong?

Comment: Protocol overhead and the way the data is serialized.  Looks like it serializes the property names on the wire.  How many bytes does it take if you change the values from the default? Did you actually look at `bytes`? I've never used FlatBuffers, but that seems to be the case from my 30 second reading of the documentation.

Comment: if I remove the default value from schema and don't assign anything in C# code, it takes 12 bytes. But it should be 0. The protocol is supposed to be defined by schema. Since both server and client have the same schema and default values, if the sent/received bytes is 0, then both client and server can interpret that as "use all defaults".

Comment: @RobertMcKee Here is the `bytes` : `16 0 0 0 0 0 10 0 8 0 0 0 0 0 6 0 10 0 0 0 0 0 10 0`. Each byte is separated by a space. I don't know why it contains this many zeros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost no serialization format saves just the raw bits of the data types to disk. If it did that, there would be no way to have forwards/backwards compatibility when extending the schema, or to know which fields are present, etc.

FlatBuffers in particular achieves this features using offsets and vtables, which cost space. It also uses alignment so the data can efficiently be read into memory. The space overhead shrinks though as your data gets bigger.

In your case you have 8 bytes of raw data (the byte has to be aligned to the shorts), a vtable offset for the root table (4 bytes), a vtable (4 fields + 2 fixed, 16bits each, total of 12 bytes) and a root table offset (4 bytes). That would be 28 bytes, but it is 24 because you're not using all fields. A fair bit gets lost here in alignment between 32-bit and 16-bit items too.

For more information on the format, read: https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_internals.html